# In Excel, How can I count duplicate names in one cell once, if they are attributed to another name

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I count duplicate names in one cell once, if they are attributed to another name in another cell.

One column A contains teachers names and column B contains student names.  I need to know how many students are attributed to each teacher only counting the student once no matter how many subjects they may take with any particular teacher.

column A: Teacher   Donald teaches 2 classes & bob takes all classes and betty only takes one, that means Donald has 2 students.

Comment: What if there are two students named Bob in each class or a different Bob for each class.  You need to have a unique ID for each student and teacher to achieve somewhat of what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table for your data (Ctrl-T), then use this formula in column C:

```
=1/COUNTIFS([Column1],"Donald",[Column2],[@Column2])
```

When you sum column C, the result will be 2, since each class Bob takes will count as 0.5

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Pivot Add-In for this. You can add data from an existing Excel Table.

I would specify the Auto-Sum method of Distinct Count for the Student column.  This will create a calculation that will always correctly count unique students, no matter how you slice or filter your Pivot Table.

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem where there are multiple people with the same first name (or both names!). Consider creating a "key" column where each entry is unique, such as student number and staff number if these are available.